# UDP Socket and ruby

Tags: ruby, http

I am having trouble to bind to a server address. I have a connection, to a server (using Savon XML Library). Now I just need to listen to that server and gather its HTTP packets that sends. The server each time sends:

```
http://200.34.12.168/Videos/1/frame/0
http://200.34.12.168/Videos/1/frame/1
http://200.34.12.168/Videos/1/frame/2
http://200.34.12.168/Videos/1/frame/3
http://200.34.12.168/Videos/1/frame/4
...
..
```

which are HTTP packets. I am trying to create a UDP server that listens to these. This is what I have so far:

```
  s = UDPSocket.new
  s.bind('200.34.12.168', 80)

  5.times do
    text, sender = s.recvfrom(16)
    puts text
  end
```

it fails at the bind function. How can I listen to a UDP connection with ruby?

The Error I get:
"`bind': Can't assign requested address - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)"

Comment: What is the error message on `bind()`? Is it not suggesting that UDP server is not available/unrecognised protocol/or something similar by any chance?  
HTTP and UDP are two completely different protocols which (AFAIR) will not understand each other, they **MAY** carry the same payload but they will not understand each other still.

Comment: @TestTest ahhh Just trying to understand your question you trying to connect a TCP server(HTTP server) using UDP connection if yes that it weird in my sense TCP and UDP are two different protocol I dont see any success in what your doing perhap the `bind` is working properly since it cannot connect to a TCP socket using UDP connection correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I added the error I get.

Comment: try launching your script as the root user

Comment: same error ? is the port 80 really free ?

Comment: well it is sending so I guess it is free

Comment: try   s.bind(nil, 80) possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a web browser running - it may already be bound to port 80..

Comment: I am not using a browser for this